# Is it possible to edit a SharePoint Online modern UI page in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I need to change the modern UI page to hide / restrict elements from general users so they cannot gain access to certain settings or page elements.  I am currently building the SPO site in readiness for moving over in a year.

I know most of the settings can be hidden through permissions, but there are always some users that 'play around' clicking on stuff they shouldn't and change things without realising.  This is a request from our data security dept and is a current feature of our on-prem SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Working with Modern means coming to grips with the fact that you won't have complete control over the markup rendered.

> I know most of the settings can be hidden through permissions, but
>   there are always some users that 'play around' clicking on stuff they
>   shouldn't and change things without realising.

No they won't if you apply permissions properly. It's when you try to hide things without properly securing them that you expose yourself to unauthorized fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to directly modify modern UI page. There is not master page for modern UI. You can embed some JS script into the page through [Script editor web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) or you can [inject CSS style through SPFx extension](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/). This 2 method could hide some elements on modern pages.

BR